# dotnet core compilation issue regarding system.data.sqlclient.dll

Tags: c#, .net-core, compilation, .net-standard

I have two build machines. the configuration seems the same.

I build the same dotnet core project on both machines but

system.data.sqlclient.dll is different. However

both files has the same version

```
 [assembly: AssemblyVersion("4.4.0.0")]

 [assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("4.6.26606.05")]

 [assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("4.6.26606.05 @BuiltBy: dlab14-DDVSOWINAGE080 @Branch: release/2.1 @SrcCode: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/7ee84596d92e178bce54c986df31ccc52479e772")]
```

but the file size is different

258192 vs 989352

the internal namespaces are different

the referenced assemblies are different

one of them (the wrong one. the small one) has such extra attribute

```
 [assembly: AssemblyMetadata("NotSupported", "True")]
```

I reinstalled/repaired many things but i couldn't make them build the same.

What is wrong? where does different system.data.sqlclient.dll come from?  in which packages might system.data.sqlclient.dll be shipped to my server? and how can i fix it?
[image]

Comment: Can you share the specific error you are encountering.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using [Microsoft.Data.SqlClient](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-the-new-microsoftdatasqlclient/) instead of System.Data.SqlClient - as a NuGet package, it's going to be the same in both locations, in addition to the other reasons for using it outlined in that article.

Comment: thanks for your reply. How does it explain why it builds the same project on another build machine correctly?

Comment: It doesn't explain why, it just offers an alternative that may help you sidestep the issue, since System.Data.SqlClient is effectively deprecated anyway.